# Objective-C classes (best practices)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, parsing

I have an `UIViewController *menuController` where i call a `NSObject` `class *parserClass` so my application starts parsing an xml and creates an `NSDictionary` from the results. I would like to get back to `menuController` that dictionary.

In `menuController` i do this:

> `[parserClass startParsing:link];`

Then in the parserClass everything works ok, but how can i return the created dictionary to the view controller.

Now i am doing the following operation, but i now it's not the best way to do this:

- when the parser finishes the document and also finishes creating the dictionary, i create a local notification with the object attached and the create the listener in the view controller. And when the listener receives a result i get that dictionary from there.

Any better ideas ? Thank you.

I liked the block suggestion but what if the parser does not finish before it reaches the comp line in the following:

> (void)startParsing:link withCompletionBlock:(myCompletion)comp
>   {
>
> parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL
>   URLWithString:link]];
>
> [parse setDelegate:self];
>       [parse parse];
>
> ```
> comp(results);
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Delegate pattern is more appropriate to send the data back to the requestor.

Comment: Blocks > delegate (cc @Wain)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use blocks:

```
[parserClass startParsing:link withCompletionBlock:ˆ(NSDictionary *results)
{
    // do something with results
}];
```

[NSXMLParser parse] method is synchronous so it will block until parsing is done. Because of that in this example it makes no sense at all to use completion block as you can simply return a value. What you are trying to achieve is probably to run parser on a background thread and then to be notified when it's done. If that is true then you can write something like this:

```
- (void)startParsing:(NSURL *)url withCompletionBlock:ˆ(NSDictionary *results)comp
{
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), 
    ˆ{
        NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [parser setDelegate:weakSelf];
        [parser parse];
        comp(weakSelf.results);
    }];
}
```

Comment: I like your suggestion but what if the parser does not finish before it reaches the comp line in the following: "- (void)startParsing:link withCompletionBlock:(myCompletion)comp { parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]]; [parse setDelegate:self]; [parse parse]; comp(results); }"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the custom delegates below is the format and you can send the message one class to another after conforming to the protocol:-

```
    @protocol sampleDelegate <NSObject>
    @required
    -(NSString *)getDataValue;
@end
@interface yourClass : NSWindowController<sampleDelegate>
{
    id<sampleDelegate>delegate;
}
@property(readwrite,assign)id<sampleDelegate>delegate;
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Delegation pattern:
[Delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html)

If you like block syntax like me you can use blocks for your purpose:
[Blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Block.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH3-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Grand Central Dispatch to achieve this faster and with cleaner code. First dispatch the parsing in a background queue and then update the UI on the main thread (you should always update UI on the main queue) like this:

```
    dispatch_queue_t jsonParsingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("jsonParsingQueue", NULL);

        // execute a task on that queue asynchronously
        dispatch_async(jsonParsingQueue, ^{

    // do the parsing here

            // UI update code on the main thread (delegates, notifications, UI updates...)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                //Update your UI here, for example [tableview reloadData]



            });
});
```

Comment: I like how easy this is to understand

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of the use of the blocks can be found [here](https://github.com/rsoldatenko/XMLConverter)